# Anatomy of a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class

If you were asked to write a simple class for instructional purposes how would you do it? I'm thinking neat and indicative. One that could produce objects. Maybe with a few variable types without getting too complicated.

As a suggestion it could be a `Person` class, with three attributes per object: name, nationality, greeting, but I'm not sure if this would lend itself to maximum instructional value for minimum lines of code?

I'm hoping to get an answer from an expert who's written thousands of Ruby classes and could distill their expertise into the perfect class for instruction.

Comment: Please, elaborate on `instructional`.

Comment: By instructional I mean that it can be shown to a beginner and not overwhelm. So it would feature no obscure syntax or other distractions but still feature all the basic elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can start off by showing people the easiest possible class if all you need to is track state in instance variables:

```
class Person < Struct.new(:name, :nationality, :greeting) ; end

puts Person.new("b1_", "Somewhere", "Heydiho")
#=> #<struct Person name="b1_", nationality="Somewhere", greeting="Heydiho">
```

As a next step, show the class defined in a more "traditional" way:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :nationality, :greeting

  def initialize(name, nationality, greeting)
    @name = name
    @nationality = nationality
    @greeting = greeting
  end

  def to_s
    "#@name is from #@nationality and says \"#@greeting\""
  end

  def say_hi(name)
    "#@greeting, #{name}"
  end
end
```

Then you could do something similar with `attr_accessor` and then finally with custom setters and getters. IMHO that shows a nice progression.

Comment: Thx. Gotta be careful though. I know Rubyists by nature are minimilists and take pride in exteme brevity, but such code can sometimes not be good for instruction. Your second attempt looks close but still needs a few methods, and just for the sake of comparison, another type of variable.

Comment: Hm, I've been teaching Ruby courses for over 3 years now, people generally don't seem to have problems with the things I just showed you. If you want leave of the `Struct` example. In the second one there's no "extreme brevity", it's how most people would define a class like that. Teachning unidiomatic code doesn't help anyone.

Comment: So, added some more methods, maybe that helps you a bit more.

Comment: The `Struct` I think is too cryptic but I think you're right to add some syntax for a parent class. Possibly something like `Human` as parent would work. Hmmm, Human...?

Comment: Why don't you make another class that inherits from `Person` instead? You could do something stupid like `VIP` and add `job` as an instance variable so we know what the person is famous for. BTW: SO etiquette is to upvote helpful answers and to accept that ones that answered your question if there is one...